# Pattern matching 0-99

Tags: linux, find

I have a `find` command to find a jar file based on a glob pattern I am working on. However, it is not yielding any results. The pattern of the file name looks like this: `lib-core-x.x.x.jar` where `x` can be a one or two digit number. I need a POSIX compliant way to match the last digit, which can be a number between 0-99.

`Code`:

```
find /usr/share -maxdepth 5 -path '*/lib-core-*.*.[[:digit:]].jar'
```

`Example String`:

```
lib-core-2.15.20.jar
```

This works if the last number is single digits, but not double digits.

Comment: You are not using any regex, only a glob pattern.

Comment: Use `-regex` if you want to match a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a regular expression in a glob pattern, which doesn't work.

You could use two glob patterns separated with `-o`, one for 1-digit numbers, the other for 2-digit numbers.

And since you're just matching the filename part, use `-name` rather than `-path`.

```
find /usr/share -maxdepth 5 \( -name 'lib-core-*.*.[0-9].jar' -o -name 'lib-core-*.*.[1-9][0-9].jar' \)
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially i'd say that you probably want to use `-name` instead of `-path`, which matches against the file's basename (seeing as you've prefixed your `-path` with `*/`). But seeing as your problem is regexpattern related (and `-path` doesnt do regex) and you want posix compliance, you likely want to look into:

```
find -regextype posix-egrep -regex .....
```